# Postman giving invalid url for curl request when using jq

Tags: curl, postman

Below is the request curl.

```
curl -u <username> -X GET '<Request url>' | jq '. | [.| map(.) | .[] | {fileName: .fileName, uuid: .uuid, description: .description, size_in_bytes: .size}]'
```

The function added at the end of the curl needed to be handled to get the required output, is there a way the postman can handle this?

Comment: You're using other tools like jq there, so you need to find a way how to achieve the same with Postman, but Postman won't do anything with jq.

Comment: Thanks, so no support for jq in curl for the postman.